# java Linked List wrapper classes

Tags: java

I'm writing a method that is suppose to look up and return the value of of an element in a Linked-List, explicitly defined to hold Boolean values (wrapper class).

here is the code:

```
 public boolean lookup(int index) {
  LLNode<Boolean> nodeptr = getFirst();
  for(int i = 0; i < index; i ++){
    if(nodeptr == null)
      return false; // ??????
    nodeptr = nodeptr.getNext();
  }
  return nodeptr.getElement();
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when i try and return the element at the specified index (if it passes the condition where i get out of the for loop) it tells me:

```
   incompatible types: Boolean cannot be converted to boolean
```

I thought this was strange as I was under the assumption that Java 7 should automatically unwrap my wrapper classes so i tried:

```
 public boolean lookup(int index) {
      LLNode<Boolean> nodeptr = getFirst();
      for(int i = 0; i < index; i ++){
        if(nodeptr == null)
          return false; // ??????
        nodeptr = nodeptr.getNext();
      }
      boolean b = nodeptr.getElement().booleanValue();
      return b;
    }
```

but then i simply got the error:

```
 Error: cannot find symbol
 symbol:   method booleanValue()
 location: class java.lang.Object
```

which i don't understand since I explicitly looked up and copy/pasted this method from the API and its in the lang package so it should auto-import. I Still got the same error when i manually imported this package.

Any suggestions?

I've been asked to post the LLNode class:

```
public class LLNode<T> {

  private LLNode<T> next;

  private LLNode<T> last;

  private T element;

  public LLNode(T element, LLNode<T> next, LLNode<T> last) {
    this.element = element;
    this.next = next;
    this.last = last;
  }

  private void  setElement(T element) {
    this.element = element;
  }
  public T getElement() {
    return element;
  }

  public LLNode<T> getNext(){
    return next;
  }

  public LLNode<T> getLast() {
    return last;
  }

  public void setNext(LLNode<T> next) {
    this.next = next;
  }

   public void setLast(LLNode<T> last) {
    this.last = last;
  }


}
```

the getFirst()  method:

```
protected LLNode<Boolean> getFirst() {
   return first;
 }
```

Comment: Can you show  code for LLNode?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code from `LLNode`?  Could be the issue is there.

Comment: Can't you simply modify return type of `lookup` to `Boolean` instead?

Comment: I'd have expected an index lookup to be `get(index)` and it would either return the `Boolean` at `index` or a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Can you show us the `getFirst()` method?

Comment: And just confirming - is `first` declared as an `LLNode<Boolean>`?

Comment: You're using Generics in the `LLNode<T>` class.  Where is `LLNode<Boolean> getFirst()` implemented?

Comment: LLNode<Boolean> is implemented inside the LinkedList( Linked List is declared as having its type be Boolean).

Comment: You should be able to simply return getElement().
Try to initialize `nodeptr` with a new node: `LLNode<Boolean> nodeptr = new LLNode<>(true, null, null);` and lookup index 0. If this works, then the problem lies in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Change your lookup method to:

```
public boolean lookup(int index) {
  LLNode<Boolean> nodeptr = getFirst();
  for(int i = 0; i < index; i ++){
    if(nodeptr == null)
      return false; // ??????
    nodeptr = nodeptr.getNext();
  }
  Object element = nodeptr.getElement();
  if( element != null && element instanceof Boolean )
  {

     return ((Boolean)element).booleanValue();
  }

   return false;
}
```